# strcpy_s in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new to C++ . I am writing following simple code. I wanted to pass the character[40] into a function and then get the same as output.
If i put a debug at following point.
 strcpy_s(x,100,tester);

But it only takes "This" if i write "This is sent at the output". Can anyone please point out what am i missing and whats the reason for only accepting few characters.

```
// BUSTesting.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

int testFunction(char* tester);
int _tmain()
{

    char m[40];
    std::cin>>m;
    testFunction(m);
}
int testFunction(char* tester)
{

    char x[100] ;
    memset(x,100,sizeof(x));
    strcpy_s(x,100,tester);
    std::cout<<x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh dear not another "C with iostream"

Comment: The C++ way to handle strings is `std::string` rather than `char*`. This will not solve your problem here, but it will make your life much easier in general.

Comment: btw. strcpy_s is not part of standard c++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) will stop consuming input at first whitespace character. An alternative would be to use [`cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) to prevent processing of input due to whitespace.

Note to initialize an array and avoid `memset()`:

```
char x[100] = "";
```

Recommend [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which avoids specifying a maximum number of characters to read from the input stream (avoiding potential buffer overrun problems with fixed sized arrays).

Comment: You guys are correct for example if i write                   strcyp_s(m,10,"This is output);                                           Then this is working. Thanks a ton for looking into this issue:)

Answer (score 3):

Change this: `std::cin >> m;` to this `cin.getline(m, 39);`

`cin >> x` doesn't get all line characters until end-line when there is a white-space (space, tab, ...) in the input.

*Since you are using C++, it is better to use `std::string` class instead of old C-style strings.*

Answer (score 2):

`std::cin>>m` probably breaks the string on a space for some reason. Break with a debugger and check `m`'s content. If it's only `this`, you've found the problem.

Comment: It does. He should use `getline` instead.